# not getting Mysql json value with variable as a json key

Tags: mysql, json, select

```
SET @im := (SELECT items->"$.one" From fruits where id = 12);
//it's working and saved result into @im variable
```

but i need to get it with variable in a function
i tried but failed.. 
i tried concat, it too not worked, 
i tried prepare execute stmt, it too not worked.

```
SET @p := "one";
SET @im := (SELECT items->"$."@p From fruits where id = 12);
//it's not working


"$.one" ==> "$."@p
//difference..
```

help me, what's the way to get this..

Comment: This not the way Strings are concatenated in MySQL. Use `Concat()` function properly. Moreover, share the code where you have tried with Prepared Statements

Comment: i'm trying in mysql function, could you please give me code, how to get json value., json key is a variable/parameter that comes from function parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try this method it should work.

```
SET @p = 'one';
SET @sql = '(SELECT items->"$.@p" into @im From fruits where id = 12)';
SET @sql = replace(@sql,'@p',@p);
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
select @im;
```

Comment: thanks for giving answer, I'm trying, I'm using phpMyAdmin to create function, phpMyAdmin NOT saving that code, phpmyadmin returns "one or more errors have occurred while processing your request: The following query has failed: 'Function Code' "  If i comment out/remove prepare statements than it saved successfully..